# how can i parse links from a json into a dio in flutter?

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, dio

so i have this json

```
        {
            "video": "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8",
            "audio": "https://github.com/App2Sales/mobile-challenge/raw/master/os-lusiadas.pdf",
            "pdf": "https://github.com/App2Sales/mobile-challenge/raw/master/a-arte-da-guerra.mp3"
        }
```

a friend told me that i could use dio to get the media into the links into the json file, i want to get the media from the link so i could use the media to make a gridViewBuider

here is the dio code:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:files_manager/models/midia_model.dart';

class ContentProvider {
  Future<Media> getContent() async {
    try {
      var response = await Dio().get('http://www.example.com');
      return Media.fromJson(response.data);
      //print(response);
    } catch (e) {
      return Media(Media.EMPTY, Media.EMPTY, Media.EMPTY)
          .setError(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

and also my model code too:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Media {
  static const String EMPTY = "";

  late String video;
  late String audio;
  late String pdf;
  late Map<String, dynamic> httpError = {"error": false, "errorMessage": ""};

  Media(this.video, this.audio, this.pdf);

  setError(String message) {
    httpError["error"] = true;
    httpError["errorMessage"] = message;
  }

  factory Media.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Media(json['video'], json['audio'], json['pdf']);
  }

  String mediaUrl() {
    return '{ ${this.video}, ${this.audio}, ${this.pdf} }';
  }
}
```

so i have also the code to buil the gridView i'm using some code only for test the layout, but i still need to figure out how to get the media from the links to put it in the gridView

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:files_manager/models/midia_model.dart';
import 'package:files_manager/models/test_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

class AudioWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  AudioWidget({super.key});

  final List<TestModel> heros = [
    TestModel("assets/a-arte-da-guerra.mp3", "A arte da Guerra"),
  ];

  /*final List<Map> media =
      List.generate(1000000, (index) => {"id": index, "name": "Product $index"})
          .toList();*/

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
              maxCrossAxisExtent: 180,
              childAspectRatio: 1,
              crossAxisSpacing: 20,
              mainAxisSpacing: 20),
          itemCount: heros.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
            return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              child: Text(
                heros[index].title,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what seems to be the issue?

Comment: I don't see you calling the service (dio) on the view.

Comment: yes it is because i do not really know how dio works in this context

Comment: What you want to do? getting this json from service using dio and the show these links coming in json into the gridview? Correct?

Comment: yes, i would like to download the files by the links into the json and then display them files into a grid view from the device's storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After You get Data from api using dio and convert it to media object you can use this object in you Screen :
to display video file you can use this package [VideoPlayer](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)

to display Audio file you can use this package [AudioPlayer](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers)

to display Pdf file you can use this package [SyncfusionFlutterPdfViewer](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer)

and if you want download this files you can use Dio.download() and pass your url and file path (where you want to download file)
this path is the path that you can read your file again to display them in your screen